# CSS3 transition of :after pseudoelements wait to main item transition end

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I have simple problem: If I attach css transition to pseudoelement (:after, :before) and main item, animation of pseudoelement waiting to end of animation of main item. I want do both animation simultaneously. 
I have this problem only in Chrome (54.0.2840.99) in FireFox (50.0.1) its behave fine.

This fiddle showing the problem: 
https://jsfiddle.net/CptCrunch/wtse7e8b/1

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 1s linear 0s;
}

a:hover {

  color: blue;
}

a::before {
  content: "\0005B";
  margin-right: 30px;
  transition: all 1s linear 0s;
 }

a::after {
  content: "\0005D";
  margin-left: 30px;
  transition: all 1s linear 0s;
}
```

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems if you set the specific `transition` values for each of the elements (instead of using `all`) it behaves as you are intending in Chrome. I tested Firefox and it still works fine there as well.

```
a {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 1s linear 0s; /*set color only*/
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

a::before {
  content: "\0005B";
  margin-right: 30px;
  transition: margin 1s linear 0s; /*set margin only*/
 }

a::after {
  content: "\0005D";
  margin-left: 30px;
  transition: margin 1s linear 0s; /*set margin only*/
}
```

I have [updated your js.fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wtse7e8b/3/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that fix the problem. Solved!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `all` where it slits transition into 2 different transformation. use `color` for anchor and `margin` for the psuedo-elements

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 1s linear 0s;
}

a:hover {

  color: blue;
}

a::before {
  content: "\0005B";
  margin-right: 30px;
  transition: margin 1s linear 0s;
 }

a::after {
  content: "\0005D";
  margin-left: 30px;
  transition: margin 1s linear 0s;
}

a:hover::before {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

a:hover::after {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hello world!</a>
```